# How Do I Query this Data in Access Without Creating a Circular Reference

Tags: ms-access, query, ms-access-2016

I have two tables called `Events` and `EventSeasons`. `Events` define the main type of events that there can be, and `EventSeasons` stores the number of times that the events have occurred yearly. I'm trying to query them so that I can figure out which ones are ongoing (between a range of dates), but **my problem is that I also need to retroactively mark past seasons of the same event type as active**. The next diagram shows what the output should be:[image: Query Event Assertion]You can see in `EventSeason` that `IsActive` column for item 2003 is true. Therefore in `Events` the Subactive column for the item 1001 (Summer) is True. Finally back in `EventSeasons` the Retroactive column for all 1001 items is set to true.

I have actually achieved this in Excel, but now that I'm trying to do it in access I feel like I'm going to create a circular reference. What I did in excel was to assign true to `IsActive` in `EventSeasons` if today's date is between range, then I assign true to `Subactive` in `Events` if there are instances of the current `EventID` marked as active in `EventSeason`. I then finally assign `RetroActive` to true if `Subactive` is true Or `IsActive` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to do what you are trying to do by using views, instead of trying to add calculated columns to the table.

**EventTheme_IsActive**

```
SELECT ThemeID, 
       EventID, 
       StartDate, 
       FinishDate, 
       IIf(Date()>=StartDate And Date()<=FinishDate,True,False) AS IsActive
FROM EventTheme;
```

**Events_Subactive**

```
SELECT e.EventID, e.Name, et.Subactive
FROM Events AS e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EventID, IIF(COUNT(*) > 0, True, False) AS Subactive 
    FROM EventTheme_IsActive 
    WHERE IsActive = TRUE 
    GROUP BY EventID)  AS et ON e.EventID = et.EventID;
```

**Events_RetroActive**

```
SELECT et.ThemeID, et.EventID, et.StartDate, et.FinishDate, et.IsActive, a.RetroActive
FROM EventTheme_IsActive AS et 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT EventID, IIF(COUNT(*) > 0, TRUE, FALSE) AS RetroActive 
    FROM EventTheme_IsActive 
    WHERE IsActive = TRUE 
   GROUP BY EventID)  AS a ON et.EventID = a.EventID;
```

These views may not be updateable but if you just need read access then this should suit your needs.

Comment: Did you mean to add `name` to EventTheme_IsActive? I see you used it in Events_Subactive.

Comment: Never mind, my bad I didn't see the `..FROM Events AS...` I'm trying them in my db right now.

Comment: It works, thank you! Also, no I don't need editing here so this works fine. I only have a problem though. In hindsight I can understand what each query is supposed to output, but I am not well acquainted with SQL, so I just don't get how the COUNT(*) works in here. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` just counts the rows. It seems a bit redundant, but it works for our current purpose: show TRUE if there is one or more rows of the current group where IsActive=TRUE.